# Spark 1.6.1 banner display

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

**Spark version: 1.6.1 for hadoop 2.6**
When I start the pyspark REPL (bin/pyspark), the SPARK logo is displayed and I see version 1.6.0 and not 1.6.1. I can't figure this out.
Note the RELEASE file in the spark home folder does show the version as 1.6.1 so I have not accidentally downloaded the 1.6.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version printed there seems to come from the Java side of things. Are you sure the Java libraries are up-to-date and not just PySpark?

Here is where the banner is printed:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/python/pyspark/shell.py#L64

It reads the version from the context which gets it from the Java context:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/python/pyspark/context.py#L316

The Java context is initialized here and is an instance of the Java [JavaSparkContext](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.scala#L123) class.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/python/pyspark/context.py#L231

Comment: I got the spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz distribution and performed a tar xvzf operation on it. Where would I look for the java libraries?

Comment: They seem to be included in that file. Maybe you haven't fully extracted it, or PySpark uses the wrong JAR for some reason. Make sure you don't have any stray `CLASSPATH` environment variables. Try moving away or deleting old `spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar` files too.

Comment: You were right! I had set the 'spark.driver.extraClassPath' to the 1.6.0 version. Thank you!